# Return an array of Palindromes - converting arraylist to array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, palindrome

I have the following code for returning palindromes in an array - the code works fine, but I am actually converting arraylist to an array - as the size is unknown - is this a costly conversion here? what will be the time complexity? new to java coding - wrote code on my own but I am stuck figuring out time complexity for array conversion..

```
public class palindrome{

public static void main(String[] args){

String[] arr = {"saw","madam","level","taco","tomot"};
String[] res = palind(arr);
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(res));
}

public static String[] palind(String[] arr){
    int count = 0;
    java.util.ArrayList<String> list = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    for(String s : arr){
            if(isPalindrome(s) == true){
                count++;
                list.add(s);
            }
        }
    String[] a = list.toArray(new String[count]);
    return a;
}

public static boolean isPalindrome(String s){
 return s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
}
}
```

Comment: the cost is "try it find out", really. There is no real need to ever do array conversion here, just use `ArrayList<String>` for all your data. With an `import java.util.ArrayList;` at the top, so don't use fully namespace-qualified object syntax all over the place. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Should be O(n), where n is size of array.  I'm seeing n time for traversing the array, with constant time for each step of the traversal.

Answer (score 0):

It is a costly conversion if you can work around it. If there is no way around it, then, well, even if it is costly otherwise, you have no choice.

A workaround is to give up on returning an array. What if you chose to return a `List<String>` from the `palind` method:

```
public static List<String> palind(String[] arr) {
//..
}
```

And if it is not too much of a hassle, you can even accept a `List<String>` here to make it array-free.